# Pass Array as an object to PLSQL Procedure

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a requirement to generate array in JavaScript and create an object of that array which we are sending to the plsql procedure. Can anyone please let me know how to achieve this?

```
function add_array(theForm){
  var myArray=new Array()
  for (var i=0;i < theForm.Selected.length; i++)
  {
    if(theForm.Selected[i].checked) {
      something like this for generating array 
      myArray[] = theForm.Selected[i].value;
    }
  }
```

How to create object of array in AJAX and pass that object to below URL?

```
  var url = "search_pkg.save_items?vitems";
  var urlParams = "";
  var urlParams1 = "";
  var xmlhttp = js_getXMLHTTPRequest();
  var xmlContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  urlParams1 =arrayobject;
  urlParams = urlParams1;
  xmlhttp.open("POST", url, false);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", xmlContentType);
  xmlhttp.send(urlParams);
  theForm.action = ("search_pkg.check_out?vitems="+xmlhttp.responseText);
  vCheckedCount =vCheckedCount +1;
  theForm.submit();
}
```

Comment: I tried to reformat your code to make it more readable, but it's unclear where the function `add_array` ends.  Please make sure that at least the curly brackets match. That said, your whole question is a bit hard to comprehend. What kind of server software are you using?

Comment: we are using oracle webtoolkit in which we are writing plsql codes inside HTML and javascript.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you do not have to do much on the client side - just create a PL/SQL procedure that accepts a VARCHAR2-table as parameter and send the form as it is (i.e. with several identically named HTTP-parameters, which will automagically populate the VARCHAR2-table parameter)